# OpenCV trying to read or write to video file causes VIDEOIO exception "Can't find starting number" (icvExtractPattern)

Tags: c++, opencv

So for a school project, I am trying to use `cv::VideoCapture` to open a `.avi` file to perform some image processing on it. Also, I am trying to record the video from my (Laptop) camera and save it to a file `out.avi`. Both times I encountered more or less the same exception.
I am using `OpenCV 4.1.2` and CLion on Linux Mint.

Trying to use `cv::VideoCapture vid(0);` works perfectly fine, it shows the output from the Laptop's camera. However, when specifying a path to a video file to open, I get the following error:

```
VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[ERROR:0] global /home/aris/dev/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (116) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.1.2-dev) /home/aris/dev/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): ../example_depth.avi in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

When trying to create a `cv::VideoWriter` object (to save the camera video ouput to a file) using:

```
cv::VideoWriter vidWrit("out.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, cv::Size(width, height), true);
```

I am encountering this error:

```
[ERROR:0] global /home/aris/dev/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (392) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.1.2-dev) /home/aris/dev/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): out.avi in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

Which looks kind of similar to the other one.

Here is a minimal example (note that the program still shows the camera output in `task == "write"`):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main ()
{
    std::string task = "write";
    if(task == "read") {    // Read from .avi file
        system("pwd");  // Print current path
        cv::VideoCapture vid("../example_depth.avi");   // Throws first exception "Inappropriate ioctl for device"

        int key = 0;
        cv::Mat frame;
        while (key != 27) {
            vid >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;

            cv::imshow("Video", frame);
            key = cv::waitKey(25);
        }
    } else if (task == "write") {   // Write Laptop video to file
        cv::VideoCapture vid(0);    // Video from camera

        int width = vid.get(cv::VideoCaptureProperties::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
        int height = vid.get(cv::VideoCaptureProperties::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        cv::VideoWriter vidWriter("out.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, cv::Size(width, height), true);   // Throws second exception

        int key = 0;
        cv::Mat frame;
        while (key != 27) {
            vid >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;
            vidWriter.write(frame);

            cv::imshow("Video", frame);
            key = cv::waitKey(25);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been looking for a solution for two days now. Maybe I am missing some library or OpenCV didn't get installed correctly, I don't know about that (yes, I've tried 'recompiling' OpenCV). I used [this](https://blog.zhajor.com/2016/10/install-opencv-and-make-a-test-project-with-clion/) tutorial to make all the OpenCV files.

Comment: make sure to close the video file before leaving your application.

Comment: @Micka Yes your are right but I would figure that since the program doesn't even get to that point, that it wouldn't be neccessary for a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Did the file you want to write to (`out.avi`) already exist?

I got this error with `opencv-python==4.1.2.30` and changing the output to a filepath that did not exist solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this issue a couple of times. First check if the path to the video is correct. In your case, "out.avi" should exist. So this is probably is a dependency or conflict issue. My speculation is that this error occurs when a backend video encoder library conflicts with OpenCV. Try reinstalling the libraries. I suggest you follow the instructions from the [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), and [open an issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues) if you keep experiencing problems.