# Video capturing with OpenCV errors

Tags: python, opencv, video, windows-10

How do I read a video using OpenCV?
I read like this:

```py
video = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/chaplin.avi")
```

And I get this error:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (142) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:
OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): videos/chaplin.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

Could not open video
```

Comment: what is the absolute path to the video?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, compilation and linking ok, but the same cryptic error occurs at running.

It happened (with Windows) when opencv_videoio_ffmpeg430_64.dll was not accessible (it seems to be silently called by another opencv lib). Either you did not build opencv with the -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON, or alternatively your dll is not in the path.

Comment: i can't understand... can you explain more what should i do?

Comment: refer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579987/opencv-trying-to-read-or-write-to-video-file-causes-videoio-exception-cant-fin